# Writing XML strips trailing spaces

Tags: c++, xml, whitespace, msxml

I am trying to write an XML file using MSXML4.  It works fine except when I have a data element with a trailing space which must be preserved.

Given the following code to insert a new element:

```
const _bstr_t k_Parent      (ToBSTR("ParentNode"));
const _bstr_t k_Child       (ToBSTR("ChildNode"));
const _bstr_t k_Data        (ToBSTR("DataWithTrailingSpace "));
const _bstr_t k_Namespace   (ToBSTR("TheNameSpace"));

MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr m_pXmlDoc;

m_pXmlDoc->async = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXmlDoc->validateOnParse = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXmlDoc->resolveExternals = VARIANT_FALSE;
m_pXmlDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = VARIANT_TRUE;

MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pElement = m_pXmlDoc->createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, k_Child, k_Namespace);
MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pParent = m_pXmlDoc->selectSingleNode(k_Parent);

pElement->put_text (k_Data);

MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr pNewChild = pParent->appendChild(pElement);
```

If I check "pNewChild->text", the text still contains the trailing space.  When I try writing it to a file:

```
std::string xml (static_cast<std::string>(m_pXmlDoc->xml));

std::ofstream file("output.xml");

file << xml << std::endl;

file.flush();
file.close();
```

The output is:

```
<ParentNode>
    <ChildNode>DataWithTrailingSpace</ChildNode>
</ParentNode>
```

Instead of (note the extra space behind "DataWithTrailingSpace"):

```
<ParentNode>
    <ChildNode>DataWithTrailingSpace </ChildNode>
</ParentNode>
```

I cannot figure out at what point the trailing space is getting stripped.

Can someone please provide some insights in to where this may be occurring and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved.  Don't preview your XML in Internet Explorer.  It hides trailing spaces.  Use notepad instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve whitespace then you should be using a CDATA section via `createCDATASection()` or the like.

Comment: While this preserves the space it also injects "<![CDATA[" in to the XML, which I cannot support.  The system that receives it rejects it because the 'data' is in an invalid format.

The output must be "<ChildNode>DataWithTrailingSpace </ChildNode>".

Comment: Then your receving system __does not support XML__. In XML, "<ChildNode>DataWithTrailingSpace </ChildNode>" is _exactly_ the same as "<ChildNode><![CDATA[DataWithTrailingSpace ]]></ChildNode>"

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the whitespace(s) with `&#xa0;`. That way your whitespaces should persist.

**EDIT**
Appearantly it didn't solve your problem. Then maybe you want to have a look at these sites:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757008(VS.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757885(VS.85).aspx

Comment: I cannot get that to work.  I end up with:

    <ChildNode>DataWithTrailingSpace &#xa0;</ChildNode>

The space is there, between the data and "&#xa0;".